# How to write a file to a mapped folder located on a non windows machine

Tags: c#, impersonation

I am trying to programmatically write a file on a mapped network drive.  The share is hosted on a Synology NAS running DSM.

When I map the drive on Windows 10, I specify the share "\\192.1.1.1\Share", and when prompted for credentials I supply "DS3617XS\admin" and "password".

I have attempted to Impersonate the user before writing the file.

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    using ( new Impersonator("admin", "DS3617XS", "password" ) )
    {
        //Write the file
    }
}


public class Impersonator
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUserName,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern int DuplicateToken(
        IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern  bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr handle);
    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    public Impersonator(
        string userName,
        string domainName,
        string password )
    {
        ImpersonateValidUser( userName, domainName, password );
    }
    private void ImpersonateValidUser(
        string userName, 
        string domain, 
        string password )
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            if ( RevertToSelf() )
            {
                if ( LogonUser(
                    userName, 
                    domain, 
                    password, 
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
                    ref token ) != 0 )
                {
                    if ( DuplicateToken( token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate ) != 0 )
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity( tokenDuplicate );
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception( Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( token!= IntPtr.Zero )
            {
                CloseHandle( token );
            }
            if ( tokenDuplicate!=IntPtr.Zero )
            {
                CloseHandle( tokenDuplicate );
            }
        }
    }

    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

}
```

An Exception is thrown "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"

Comment: Is that a typo in your post or in your drive mapping?  It should be `\\192.1.1.1\Share` (prefixed with two backslashes).  Does the mapped drive work when accessed from Explorer?  Also, drive mappings are per-user, so if your code impersonates a user different than the one that made the mapping, they won't see the mapping.  Finally, is `DS3617XS` a domain or a machine name?  If the latter, I don't think you can impersonate another machine's local account.

Comment: Thanks BACON!  That was a typo, and YES I am able to use explorer to open the folder and read/write files.

Comment: DS3617XS is the machine name.  The server is not a windows machine and is not part of a domain.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the share/file directly without impersonation?  Since the share is already mapped as `DS3617XS\admin` I don't think there's any advantage to impersonating `DS3617XS\admin`, too, even if that were possible.  Any file operations you perform through the mapping will performed under the `admin` user's account.